# Bundle by Name Output Cluster Error

Tags: cluster-computing, labview

Im just getting into using LabView and I ran into an error I can't seem to get rid of while working on a small sample exercise with the Bundle by Name Function.

Under here you can find my front panel, block diagram & error message displayed.

[image: This is my Block Diagram]

[image: Front panel]

[image: Error]

The output cluster is all indicators and all the items in the Enums have the same values, I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Can anyone help out?..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete your output cluster, than right click on bundle function and create indicator. 
The problem is your output cluster order is other than cluster constant order. 
Please read about type definitions and consider using them to avoid problems like this in the future.

Comment: Had already figured it out by myself after poking around some more but still didn't know how I exactly solved it. Thanks for providing some more insight!

Comment: Happy to hear all going fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your indicator and the cluster constant are actually the same type. A short cut would be to delete the existing control and just creat a new on by right clicking on the terminal of the unbundle by name and selecting create>>indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Given the error message, I would say that it's because of the difference in elements order, between the constant you're giving to the Bundle, and the indicator wired to the output.

You can make sure of order consistency by right-clicking on the *border* of the cluster constant, and select `AutoSizing -> Arrange vertically`. This will order the elements, and to fix it you re-order by selecting `Reorder controls in cluster` in the same menu. Of course, you can also fix the ordering of the indicator.